# What is the best way to check if Ajax call is 200 OK if I'm returning the table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ajax-request

I have a question about ajax success. So in previous situations I have returned Data something like ID but now in this case I'm returning entire table. So I would like to check if Ajax was successful(200 OK) before I retrieve my data. What is the best way to do that? Also I use new way to retrieve data and check for errors with JQuery. Here is example of my code:

```
<div id="box"></div>

function getSlots(fld){
    var userID = '134';

    $j.ajax({
        type:  'POST',
        url:  'AjaxData.html',
        cache:  false,
        data:  {'userID':userID},
            dataType: "html",
            async:   false
        })  
        .done(function(html){
            $j('#box').html(html);
        })
        .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){ 
            gwLogIt(errorThrown);
        }); 
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need to check for `200 OK`?  Doesn't `.done` check for that for you?  What problem are you facing with this code?

Comment: P.S. Why are you using `async: false`?  I wouldn't suggest using that because it will lock up the user's browser until the call is done.

Comment: I do not know if .done actually check for that. In the past I was putting if statement inside of success.

Comment: What would you recommend to use instead?

Comment: Instead of async: false? Or I do not need that.

Comment: Nothing, remove that line. Why are you using it?  AJAX is supposed to be *asynchronous*.

Comment: I think that I used on one of my previous pages and I haven't removed. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to check. The various callbacks are called under the following conditions:

- `.done()` or `success:` are called when the AJAX call is successful.
- `.fail()` or `error:` are called when there's an error (either from the server or in the jQuery code that parses the response).
- `.always()` or `complete:` are called in either case.

Answer (score 2):

from official docs:

```
$.ajax({
  statusCode: {
    404: function() {
      alert( "page not found" );
    }
  }
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

also if you use something like babel to transpile ES6, you can use `fetch` api for ajax calls. I personally stopped using jQuery ±2 years ago.. when moved to React world :)